# About problems that occur after updating to GMA 8.1

Tags: ios, google-mobile-ads

I'm using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK in iOS, but after updating from 7.36.0 to 8.1.0, I get the following error.

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'GADUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate'
```

Could you tell me the cause and solution?

Comment: Any update on the above